# Cannot implement two interfaces that have the same method name

Tags: php, oop, interface

This doesn't work:

```
interface TestInterface
{
    public function testMethod();
}

interface TestInterface2
{
    public function testMethod();
}

class TestClass implements TestInterface, TestInterface2
{

}
```

Gives me the error:

> Fatal error: Can't inherit abstract function TestInterface2::testMethod() (previously declared abstract in TestInterface).

Is that correct? Why is this not allowed? Doesn't make sense to me.

This also happens with abstract functions, for example if you implement an interface and then inherit from a class that has an abstract function of the same name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It makes no sense to implement two interfaces containing methods with the same signatures.

The compiler cannot know if the methods actually have the same purpose - if not, it would mean that at least one of the interfaces **cannot** be implemented by your class.

Example:

```
interface IProgram { function execute($what); /* executes the given program */ }
interface ISQLQuery { function execute($what); /* executes the given sql query */ }

class PureAwesomeness implements IProgram, ISQLQuery {
    public function execute($what) { /* execute something.. but what?! */ }
}
```

So as you see, it's impossible to implement the method for both interfaces - and it'd also be impossible to call the method which actually implements the method from a given interface.

Comment: But the whole point of interfaces is that they don't have implementation though. What if you want to make your class able to be passed to a function that specifies one interface for a parameter and another one which specifies another interface but both have one method in common? A method name like "getName()" is not going to have a different purpose on a different interface.

Comment: In that case you should create a new interface, e.g. `INamed` which just contains the `getName()` method.

Comment: They don't have implementation, but they do have semantics, at least implicitly. While you *could* implement a method in an interface to have an entirely different meaning in different classes which use it, this would be contrary to the spirit of interfaces. However, if you implement two different interfaces, there is no guarantee that their specifiers knew anything of each other, and hence that the similarly-named methods had similar semantics. I guess you could make each interface extend a common interface that contained the common method.

Comment: Implementing interfaces with the same signatures works perfectly fine for me using PHP 5.3.10 on Windows.  It does not work on my PHP 5.3.3 Linux setup; There, I get the same error as the original poster.

Comment: Implementing interfaces with the same signature can make sence and is even [possible since PHP-5.3.9](https://3v4l.org/NhBdL).

Comment: Only EOL versions does not support that, therefore developers which are currently looking for that answer, it's a "wrong" answer.

Answer (score 12):

It appears that current PHP versions actually can do this. I've tracked the change in behavior down to this commit:

https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/31ef559712dae57046b6377f07634ad57f9d88cf#Zend/zend_compile.c

So as of php-5.3.9 the documented behavior appears to have changed.

Answer (score 10):

[The PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) says explicitly:

> Prior to PHP 5.3.9, a class could not implement two interfaces that specified a method with the same name, since it would cause ambiguity. More recent versions of PHP allow this as long as the duplicate methods have the same signature.

Comment: I don't understand where the ambiguity could be, since there are no implementations (that's the whole point of the Interface). I can see why you wouldn't want the same method with different signatures, but, with the same signature, shouldn't this be left for the concrete implementation to deal with? Isn't that the way, for instance, Java works?

Comment: I think there is an argument for what you say: it is a decision the language designers take how far to protect you from yourself. There is no _intrinsic_ ambiguity, but if the interfaces have functions with the same signature, the semantics they require from the functions might match, or they might be entirely different.

Comment: This seems backwards. Shouldn't it only be allowed if they have  _different_ signatures? If the two methods have different signatures, then anyone calling one of the methods is explicitly calling the specific method they want. Even if the two methods have two completely different goals, it's ok because the correct method will be called. However, if the two methods have the same signature and the goal of each method is completely different, there will be no way to have a single method that can serve both purposes, so a single method doesn't make sense. Can anyone provide some counter rationale?

Answer (score 4):

```
interface BaseInterface
{
    public function testMethod();
}

interface TestInterface extends BaseInterface
{
}

interface TestInterface2 extends BaseInterface
{
}

class TestClass implements TestInterface, TestInterface2
{
    public function testMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not allowed, because PHP cannot be sure which interface has the method you want. In your case they are identical, but imagine if they had different parameters.

You should reconsider your application design.