# Implementing two interfaces having the same function in c#

Tags: c#, interface

Can we implement two interfaces having the same function in c#

```
interface TestInterface
{
    public function testMethod();
}

interface TestInterface2
{
    public function testMethod();
}

class TestClass implements TestInterface, TestInterface2
{

}
```

Is this possible?

I found it is not possible in php [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497613/cannot-implement-two-interfaces-that-have-the-same-method-name)

Comment: Yes, use an explicit interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Sure, but you will have to prefix your calls to the methods as they will otherwise be ambiguous. The compiler will show you in case you omit the interface name anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you have to qualify the method names with the interface names:

```
    class TestClass : TestInterface, TestInterface2
    {
        void TestInterface.testMethod()
        {

        }

        void TestInterface2.testMethod()
        {
        }
    }
```

Although I wouldn't recommend having such a structure - it should be done just for academic interests :-)

Comment: [Link to msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx) Also, in the language specification under "13.4.1 Explicit interface member implementations  387" , you might want to quote from there, as well as the msdn page.

Comment: Sometimes you might not have a choice :-)