# php implement same functions from differents interfaces

Tags: php

there are many php components, each of them requires implementing their own interfaces or something like psr.

If i have to implement two different interfaces from different components and those interfaces have same functions in other words, same signatures or function names,

Can I implement those interfaces in one class?

like this situation.

```
interface I1FromComponent1 {
    function getName:string
}

interface I2FromComponent2 {
    function getName:Name(or NameInterface)
}

Myclass {

function getName():string {
    return $this->name;
}

}
```

Comment: This is well known problem and It can be solved using Strategy design pattern which is designed to solve this specific problem. You can find many sources from web on how to implement this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot implement two interfaces that have the same method name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497613/cannot-implement-two-interfaces-that-have-the-same-method-name)

Comment: @Dashrath Chauhan thanks for your advise, but I don't want to change my style just because of this problem.

Comment: @Julian S yes, but it's too old. problem is that the same function name do not guarantee the same functionality even in the future, php support overloading this is never solved. there are psr but it is too strict to other developers.

Comment: The purpose of an interface is so that you're designing by interface, and calls to the function know what type is being returned, and can act on that appropriately. If it can return `string` and `Name`, what happens to the `string` type if your code treats the function call as if it were expecting a `Name` return type?

Comment: Maybe you could provide a real example of your problem to find a good solution

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not support method overloading, and to address this the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) states this about it's implementation of OOP...

> A class can implement two interfaces which define a method with the same name, only if the method declaration in both interfaces is identical

The purpose of an interface is to ensure consistent usage of functions throughout your code, and ties into type-hinting and code-sniffing in IDEs that support these features. Without overloading, how is the code meant to handle something like this?

```php
// Works for string return type, but will only return a string for
// NameInteface return type if it implements the __toString() method
echo $this->getName();

// Works for NameInterface return type, but fails for string return type
$var2 = $this->getName()->nameMethod;
```

Your best option is to have the interfaces define different methods, one for each return type:

```php
interface I1FromComponent1 {
    function getName() : string;
}
    
interface I2FromComponent2 {
    function getNameObject() : NameInterface;
}
```

Comment: absolutely best option, if I could edit whole codes which use those interfaces! Thanks 