# PHP conflicting multiple interfaces, no errors reported

Tags: php, interface

I'm baffled by the results of this code:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

interface interface1 {
    public function myMethod1(string $param1, int $param2);
    public function myMethod2(int $param1);
}

interface interface2 {
   public function myMethod1(int $param1, string $param2, float $param3);
   public function myMethod2(float $param1);
}

class SomeClass implements interface1, interface2 {
    public function myMethod1(array $param1) {
        echo "In method2";
        var_dump($param1);
    }
    public function myMethod2( array $param1, array $param2, array $param3) {
       echo "In Method2";
       var_dump($param1);
    }
}

$c = new SomeClass();
$c->myMethod1();
$c->myMethod2();
exit;
```

The multiple interfaces are in conflict with regard to argument types and number of arguments. And the code calls the methods without any of the required arguments. The method signature is wrong for every method in the class that implements the interfaces.

The code runs with no reported errors or warnings and produces no output, but issues a code of 255. When debugging, it doesn't stop at any breakpoints. Shouldn't at least one error or warning message be thrown?

Comment: `'E_ALL'` should not be in quotes.

Comment: You also need `<?php` at the beginning. When I fix those things I get an error about the interface compatibility.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497613/cannot-implement-two-interfaces-that-have-the-same-method-name

Comment: @LarsStegelitz That's not the same, the methods have the same signature there.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php `Warning
A class can implement two interfaces which define a method with the same name, only if the method declaration in both interfaces is identical.`

Comment: PHP does not have function/method overloading. You cannot declare a function or method more than once even if the parameters differ. You _can_ declare identical methods in different interfaces so long as their signatures are _identical_, though good practice would imply that those should likely be broken out into their own interface.

Comment: Even without the quotes around 'E_ALL', I still get no errors. I know that the errors in the code are errors. My question is, why are there no errors displayed.  And my code does have a PHP tag at the top, I just forgot to copy it here.

Comment: look into the error log, it's a fatal error

Comment: The error: https://3v4l.org/N1T30

Answer (score 0):

Pilot Error. Thanks to Sammitch's and Barmar's comments, the mystery is solved. First, putting 'E_ALL' in quotes suppressed the error. When I fixed that, I wanted to make sure E_STRICT was on, so, like an idiot, I changed it to E_ALL & E_STRICT, which also suppressed the error, until I changed it to E_ALL | E_STRICT (E_ALL by itself would have done it). Thanks for the help.